# Change default message when assisstant misunderstands user

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have created a google action, which takes in three parameters, I have done training phrases for many word combinations, but sometimes it will not pick it up.

I set my input parameters in the dialog flow to number1, number2, and number3.

It seems by default, if it misses a value it will say: "what is `$varName`"

however, this could be misleading to users since it may be unclear if it just prompts the user for 'what is number3'.

Id like to edit this response to be a more descriptive message.

I hope this is clear enough - I cant really post any code since its all concerning this dialogflow ui...

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add prompt variations for capturing parameters in an entity follow the "adding prompt variation" explained [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/slot-filling). Just add variations to prompts as below or handle it from webhook by enabling [slot-filling for webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/webhook-slot-filling).
[image]

If you want to ask questions when the agent did not understand the intent then you can either use a Default Fallback Intent for a generic reply or create a follow-up fallback intent for the intent you are targetting.
[image] 
or
 [image]

Comment: if the bot is stuck in extracting `parameter value` then it will continue to ask that prompt only, it will not go to `follow-up fallback intent`. correct me if i'm wrong coz i have faced same issue.

Comment: Then you will need to use slot filling for  webhook and use reprompt to keep a counter and set the lifespan of context.

Comment: yeah.. i will try that now